# Unable to add text suggestion from a file to my textbox in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, windows-10-universal

I am making a Universal Windows App, which includes inserting text into a textbox. I want my app to suggest text from a file to insert to the textbox. But I could not find that property. I have added the textbox in the MainPage.xaml through XAML tags. I believe there is a property for this operation in WPF API. I am just not sure if I can do this in UWP.

Comment: Do you want to make a `TextBox` behavior like [AutoSuggestBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt280217.aspx)?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT I was unaware of AutoSuggestBox. So, I thought of making a textbox behave like AutoSuggestBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using the AutoSuggestBox control for UWP. The auto-suggest results list populates automatically once the user starts to enter text. The results list can appear above or below the text entry box.

```
<AutoSuggestBox PlaceholderText="Search" QueryIcon="Find" Width="200"
            TextChanged="AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged"
            QuerySubmitted="AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted"
            SuggestionChosen="AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen"/>


private void AutoSuggestBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    // Only get results when it was a user typing, 
    // otherwise assume the value got filled in by TextMemberPath 
    // or the handler for SuggestionChosen.
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
    {
        //Set the ItemsSource to be your filtered dataset
        //sender.ItemsSource = dataset;
    }
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_SuggestionChosen(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxSuggestionChosenEventArgs args)
{
    // Set sender.Text. You can use args.SelectedItem to build your text string.
}


private void AutoSuggestBox_QuerySubmitted(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxQuerySubmittedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ChosenSuggestion != null)
    {
        // User selected an item from the suggestion list, take an action on it here.
    }
    else
    {
        // Use args.QueryText to determine what to do.
    }
}
```

Here is the [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics) to the GitHub repo for a complete UI basics sample.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply for UAP but with WPF there's a trick that allows a "dropdown suggestion list". You can replace text box with a combobox and populate it's items when user types. This can be achieved by doing bindings like so:

```
Text={ Binding Path=meCurrentValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }

ItemsSource={Binding Path=meFilteredListOfSuggestions, Mode=TwoWay }
```

Then within your viewmodel you can simply do:

```
public string meCurrentValue
{
get { return _mecurrentvalue; }
set { 
_mecurrentvalue = value;
updateSuggestionsList();
NotifyPropertyChanged("meCurrentValue");
NotifyPropertyChanged("meFilteredListOfSuggestions"); // notify that the list was updated
ComboBox.Open(); // use to open the combobox list
}

public List<string> meFilteredListOfSuggestions
{
get{return SuggestionsList.Select( e => e.text.StartsWith(_mecurrentvalue));}
}
```

EDIT:
Remember to set the editable value of the combobox to TRUE, this way it will act like a normal textbox.